# 3D view "orthographic" isn't really orthographic?

Tags: 3d-view, orthographic

When I switched to orthographic view with <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>, the view in my 3D view doesn't look to be properly orthographic at all. Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean "not orthographic at all"? the length of the front and back edges are exactly the same, same thing for left and right, the angles are the same, etc... please be more specific...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view *is* orthographic. I think what you're seeing is an optical illusion. The angles you have described as 'low' and 'high' are in fact the same, as shown below where I have rotated the the image and inserted horizontal parallel lines:

[image]

The lines marked in red are also of equal length and parallel.